# Missing if statement when trying to convert a spatial polygon into a raster object

Tags: r, r-raster, rasterizing

I am trying to convert a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` into a `raster` object. My current script (below) appears to achieve my desired outcome except when number of columns `nCol` and number of rows `nRow` are set to 100 when I receive a cryptic error message: `Error in if (x2a < rxmn) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`. This error message appears to suggest there is an if statement somewhere which is not filled but I am unsure where this is or how to get around this.

```
# Convert to raster ----
randomcluster_raster <- raster::rasterize(
  SpatialPolygons_df,
  raster::raster(matrix(NA, nRow, nCol)),
  field = SpatialPolygons_df@data[, 1],
  fun = "mean",
  update = TRUE,
  updateValue = "all",
  na.rm = TRUE
)
```

Comment: I think that this is a result of your using `matrix(NA, nRow, nCol)`.  You might try `matrix(0, nRow, nCol)`

Comment: Thank you @G5W that has solved the issue.